# capture information from html page and popup window

Tags: php, html

i have an html page with text filed , and an action button to open a popup like this example

`http://www.andwecode.com/playground-demo/pop-up-login-signup-box-jquery/#modal`

(hit login to see the popup) who had also a two text fields , how i can collect the text entered in the 3 boxes (the one in the page and the two in the popup window) simultaneously with a php file ? cause i need to send them all to my email
an exemple of my php file :

```
<?php
$txt1 = "textfield 1 : ".$_POST['textfield1'];
$txt2= "textfield 2 : ".$_POST['textfield2'];
$tx3= "textfield 3 : ".$_POST['textfield3'];
$message = "
$txt1
$txt2
$txt3
";
$to = "myemail@example.com";  
$subject = "data :".$txt1;
$headers = "From: <myemail@example.com>";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$from = "example";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$from);
} 
?>
```

any idea how to collect all the text from the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP to receive the values of three different inputs in a single POST, all three inputs need to be contained within the same HTML `<form>`. Try moving HTML around so that all inputs are contained in a single form, then they should all be accessible to PHP in the `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you don't have 'name' attributes on the input tags, try something like this,

```
 <!--ALL THE HTML-->
Email: <input type="text" name="email"></input>
Password: <input type="pass" name="pass"></input>
<!--MORE HTML-->
```

SEPARATE PHP FILE!!

```
 <?php
      function getdata(){
        $email= $_GET['email']; //Email
        $pass= $_GET['pass']; //Password
        $name = $_GET['name']; //Full name (Only will apply if registering)
                };//This gets the data and gives it a variable
          //Then more php like you had already to email to yourself
    ?>
```

In simple terms, add the 'name' attribute to the inputs (`name="whatevername"`) and then use the `$_GET` in php to get the data (`$varname = $_GET['nameattributehere'];`).

Just remember!

1. To put the PHP code in a separate file with the .PHP extension on it (.HTML doesn't work!)
2. Add the 'name' attributes to the inputs
3. And on the `<form>` tag you MUST ADD THIS! `method="get" action="srcforthephpfile.php"`

Good Luck